# How to increase the font-size of a data in a flie using jquery dynamically?

Tags: jquery, listview, font-size

I have created the listview dynamically.In the listview number of items are there. Each item has there own file. When I click on the particular item that particular file data is displaying in a page which is created dynamically.

Dynamic Page for displaying file data:

```
$($.mobile.pageContainer).append('
        <div data-role="page" id="' + seq + '" class="items">
        <div data-role="content" id="desc"></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="my-footer">
            <div data-role="popup" id="textMenu" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <ul id="pageSize" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
                    <li data-icon="false"><a href="" id="textSize">Text size</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a ui-bar-a" data-theme="a">
            <div align="left" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;">
                <a href="#textMenu" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="bars" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop"></a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <a href="" data-role="button" class="addToFavoritesDiv">Bookmark</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="" data-role="button" class="shareDiv">Share</a>
            <div class="ui-block-c ui-bar-a">
            <div align="right" style="padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>');   

$('[data-role=page]#' + seq + ' [data-role=content]').load(file);
```

In this page I have a button(`#textSize`) for increasing the text size of data.
I dont known how to increase the font size of a data in a file.

```
$("#desc #textSize").click(function() {
     var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
     var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got the solution?  It seems you refer dynamic click event.  so like this `$("#textSize").on('click', function() {`

Comment: $('htm').css('font-size'); selects nothing. try to use filter() function.

Comment: @user1671639 no. I tried like this also but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for resizing the text

```
$(document).on('click', '#pagesize #textSize', function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('font-size',newFontSize);
});
```

Comment: i dont known how to change the font size of data in a file..but what i tried i already post the code

Comment: $("#textSize").on('click', function() {
  var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
   $('#desc').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('font-size',newFontSize);
});
});

Comment: replace your $('html').css('font-size'); with $('*').filter(function(){return $(this).css('font-size', '1.2em');});

Comment: yes i did the same you can see the above comment but not working